# Jquery filter plus running multiple functions

Tags: jquery

I am having trouble getting my filtered table to change views at the same time. You can see it here in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/831c8fLp/). Ignore the overlapping text for now.

What I want to do is have it change to compact or full view when the button is pressed once. This somehow works when it is the button is clicked twice.. which isn't correct.

Any ideas? I am not great at jquery but I can get things to work

See fiddle and functions at bottom.

```
  var $timeBlock = $('.timeBlock'),
      $checkboxes = $('#filters input');

  $timeBlock.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.item'
  });

  $checkboxes.change(function(){
    var filters = [];
    // get checked checkboxes values
    $checkboxes.filter(':checked').each(function(){
      filters.push( this.value );
    });
    // ['.red', '.blue'] -> '.red, .blue'
    filters = filters.join(', ');
    $timeBlock.isotope({ filter: filters });
  });

  $('#shuffle').click(function(){
    $timeBlock.isotope('shuffle');
  });

  var $items = $timeBlock.children();

  $("#isotope-reset").click(function(){
      reset();
});


$('#compact').click(function () {
    $('.item').animate({width: "30%"}, 500);
    $('.item').animate({height: "35px"}, 500);
    reset();

});


$('#full').click(function () {
    $('.item').animate({width: "455px"}, 500);
    $('.item').animate({height: "80px"}, 500);
    reset();


});

function reset() {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked',false);
    $timeBlock.isotope({
        filter: '*'
    });
}
```

Comment: what browser you have? Your fiddle is working on my Chrome 41.0.2

Comment: Chrome. I may not have been clear. Click the full view button. It will do something... Then click it again and it will do what it should do on the first click. Same with compact (it starts in compact.)

Comment: Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to put functions into the queue.

click events do a queue, if animation is completed then run next. Look at documentation on [callback complete](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

```
$(document).on('click', '#compact', function () {
    $('.item').animate({width: "30%"}, 500, function() {
        $('.item').animate({height: "35px"}, 500, function() {
            $(this).resetItems();
        });
    });
});


$(document).on('click', '#full', function () {
    $('.item').animate({width: "455px"}, 500, function() {
        $('.item').animate({height: "80px"}, 500, function() {
            $(this).resetItems();
        });
    });
});
```

event reset items, if you use jquery then register that functions into the jquery. It is not necessary but give to you good advantages of jquery

```
$.fn.resetItems = function() {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked',false);
    $timeBlock.isotope({
        filter: '*'
    });
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/831c8fLp/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the information. I was not familiar with this. It does seem very slow on switching between the two but at at least it performing the full animation.

Comment: yes but optimalize is sometimes needed. But i am glad it will help to you  move step go on.